# Pre-load tiles in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, tiles

I need to preload images (.png) / tiles in my own

```
source: new ol.source.XYZ
```

,which can it run fast to move and zoom in mobile devices.

I used **...libs/ol3/3.7.0/ol-debug.js** and as urls: urlArray ..

```
var urlArray = ["/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"];
```

and tried following parameters to force pre-loading more images than default zoom of map :
'buffer','preload'; but nothink helped/worked. As first I minimize the size of every tile, but it helped not too much.

Can be helped to preload images/tiles throught CSS and

```
div.none {display:none;background-image:url()}
```

or exist any JS function to preload images from my folders **/{z}/{x}/{y}.png** ?

Comment: Are you developing an app for mobiles?

Comment: No, Im developing single webside for mobile and desctop

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any JS or CSS function/setting that can do this. Nor Openlayers can. If you want to make things (move/zoom) faster, as I understand, the tiles (images) have to be cached on client side, in your case, each visitor (mobile) of your website.

Now, the ***only reasonable possibility*** is if you already know where your visitor is going to move, like a predetermined route. **In this case**, you could present a loading screen (or something else) while (under the screen) programmatically you move/zoom the map (this is caching the tiles).

Comment: I asked for somethink Like this :(http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/multiserver.html), which is fast  way, i tried on mobile.

Comment: So you have to configure your web server to serve your tiles from subdomains and then use a url like `http://{a-c}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, notice to `{a-c}`.